# Woocommerce: How can I run a function either after user clicks place order on the checkout page, or clicks pay for order on the order pay page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a function in woocommerce that, depending on the payment method selected, creates a new custom field in the order meta, and presents that field on the order table, if it exists. The function works as desired when going through the front end checkout. However, it does not work if I manually create an order, and the customer clicks "pay for order" on the order_pay page.

The old code that only runs after checkout looks like this:

```
// Add custom order meta data on checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'add_custom_order_meta', 10, 2 );

function add_custom_order_meta( $order, $data ) {
    // Get the payment method for the order
    $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();

    // Only add custom meta data for certain payment methods
    if ( in_array( $payment_method, array( 'bacs', 'cheque' ) ) ) {
        // Get the order total
        $order_total = $order->get_total();
        
        // Set the currency to convert to based on payment method
        $currency_to = ( $payment_method === 'bacs' ) ? 'hkd' : 'thb';
        
        // Convert the order total to the selected currency
        $converted_total_gptlove = get_conversion( 'number=' . $order_total . '&from=usd&to=' . $currency_to . '&dp=2' );
        
        // Set the currency symbol and code based on payment method
        $currency_symbol = ( $payment_method === 'bacs' ) ? '$' : '฿';
        $currency_code = ( $payment_method === 'bacs' ) ? 'HKD' : 'THB';
        
        // Update the order meta data with the converted total and currency info
        $order->update_meta_data( 'converted_total_gptlove', $currency_symbol . $converted_total_gptlove . ' ' . $currency_code );
    }
}

// Add custom meta field to order details on Thank You page and order emails
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'add_custom_order_item_totals', 10, 3 );
function add_custom_order_item_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    
    // Get the value of the custom field "converted_total_gptlove" for the current order
    $converted_total_gptlove = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'converted_total_gptlove', true );
    
    // If the custom field is not empty, add it as a new row to the order details table
    if ( ! empty( $converted_total_gptlove ) ) {
        $total_rows['converted_total_gptlove'] = array(
            'label' => __( 'Converted Total:', 'woocommerce' ), // Set the label for the new row
            'value' => $converted_total_gptlove, // Set the value for the new row
        );
    }
    
    // Return the modified order details table with the new row added
    return $total_rows;
}
```

My modified code still runs during checkout, but it doesn't trigger after the user clicks "pay for order". What am I doing wrong here?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'add_custom_order_meta' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_receipt_order_pay', 'add_custom_order_meta' );

function add_custom_order_meta( $order ) {

    // Get the payment method for the order
    $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();

    // Only add custom meta data for certain payment methods
    if ( in_array( $payment_method, array( 'bacs', 'cheque' ) ) ) {
        // Get the order total
        $order_total = $order->get_total();
        
        // Set the currency to convert to based on payment method
        $currency_to = ( $payment_method === 'bacs' ) ? 'hkd' : 'thb';
        
        // Convert the order total to the selected currency
        $converted_total_gptlove = get_conversion( 'number=' . $order_total . '&from=usd&to=' . $currency_to . '&dp=2' );
        
        // Set the currency symbol and code based on payment method
        $currency_symbol = ( $payment_method === 'bacs' ) ? '$' : '฿';
        $currency_code = ( $payment_method === 'bacs' ) ? 'HKD' : 'THB';
        
        // Update the order meta data with the converted total and currency info
        $order->update_meta_data( 'converted_total_gptlove', $currency_symbol . $converted_total_gptlove . ' ' . $currency_code );

    }
}

// Add custom meta field to order details on Thank You page and order emails
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'add_custom_order_item_totals', 10, 3 );
function add_custom_order_item_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    
    // Get the value of the custom field "converted_total_gptlove" for the current order
    $converted_total_gptlove = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'converted_total_gptlove', true );
    
    // If the custom field is not empty, add it as a new row to the order details table
    if ( ! empty( $converted_total_gptlove ) ) {
        $total_rows['converted_total_gptlove'] = array(
            'label' => __( 'Converted Total:', 'woocommerce' ), // Set the label for the new row
            'value' => $converted_total_gptlove, // Set the value for the new row
        );
    }
    
    // Return the modified order details table with the new row added
    return $total_rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for it

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'add_custom_order_meta' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_receipt_order_pay', 'add_custom_order_meta' );

function add_custom_order_meta( $order, $data = null ) {
    // Use the appropriate parameter based on the hook that triggered the function
    $payment_method = ($data !== null) ? $data['payment_method'] : $order->get_payment_method();

    // rest of the function code remains the same...
}
```

Comment: It still works on checkout, but for some reason, the function doesn't trigger when clicking "pay for order" from the order-pay page. Is woocommerce_receipt_order_pay the right action to use?